# Create CSV with referencing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I am working on creating a csv file using to_csv($outfile.csv') in python pandas, Basically i wanted to create macro variable name for csv file rather then giving it into the to_csv function. Any lead would really appriciated : )

```
outfile = CNR_FCS_MAY_T_2020_FX

df.to_csv('outfile.csv')
print("query export ran")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below part is working for me now : )

```
 outfile = 'CNR_FCS_MAY_T_2020_FX.csv'
 df.to_csv(outfile) print("query export ran")
```

Answer (score -1):

Whats wrong with this?

```
outfile = 'CNR_FCS_MAY_T_2020_FX.csv'

df.to_csv(outfile)
print("query export ran")
```

Comment: Below part is working for me now : )
'
outfile = 'CNR_FCS_MAY_T_2020_FX.csv' 

df.to_csv(outfile)
print("query export ran")
'